# Why to return pointer after inserting node in Link Lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I don't understand why we have to return pointers to the head node after a node has been added to a linked list.

```
struct node *append(int v) {
    struct node *ptr;
    struct node *t;
    ptr=head;
    while (ptr->next != tail) ptr = ptr->next;
    t=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof *t);
    t->value=v;
    t->next = tail;
    ptr->next = t;
    return ptr; // why return ptr?
}
```

Comment: I think you have to explain something more about the context to get answered.

Comment: You are not returning "pointer to head node" here; that must have been a external variable so no need to return. You are returning a pointer to a node just before the inserted node. It may be used to undo the append and other operations depending upon you requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of the context of your problem.  Usually in linked list problems you have to return the head of the list so you can have your data structure consistent, but I infer from your code that the head is a global variable.

Unless the code that are invoking this function needs to know the location of the new node created, you don't need to return the node since your head is a global variable (again, if my assumption is correct).

Besides this, I suggest to revise your function since I see some cases you are missing here (what if the list comes empty and you have to change the head for example?)

Answer (score 0):

Linked lists are often implemented with a NULL head when the list is empty. In this case, you have to return the head of the list when the head is a local variable, or when it is a global and you want to have more than one list using the same function. When adding a node, the head may have changed, even if adding at tail, in the case the list was empty there is a new head.

But another way to do is to always have a node at the head, just here to indicate the head, and adding/reading/deleting nodes after this head in order to treat datas in the list. In this case, returning the head is useless, because the head never change.

You can detect the tail of the list when for a node n: `n->next == NULL`, using a head equal to NULL when the list is empty, as the following code do:

```
// add at the tail of the list:
struct node * add_to_list_tail(struct node * head,int v) {
  struct node *t;
  t=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  t->value = v;
  t->next = NULL; // next is set to NULL because it is the new tail

  if(head == NULL) {
    // in the case the list is empty
    head = t; // t become the new head, because the list was empty
  } else {
    // in the case the list isn't empty
    struct node * n = head;
    // the following loop will stop when n->next == NULL, and n will point to the tail
    while(n->next != NULL) {
      n = n->next;
    }
    n->next = t;
  }      
  return head;
}

// add at the head of the list:
struct node * add_to_list(struct node * head,int v) {
    struct node *t;
    t=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    t->value = v;
    t->next = head; // make t become the new head
    return t; // return t because it is the new head
}

int main() {
  struct node * head = NULL;
  head = add_to_list(head,1);
  head = add_to_list(head,2);
  head = add_to_list_tail(head,3);
}
```

If you don't want to return the head, you can also pass a pointer to the head pointer, as parameter for the functions that manipulate the list. A short sample code:

```
void add_to_list(struct node ** head,int v) {
    struct node *t;
    t=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    t->value = v;
    // make t become the new head:
    t->next = *head;
    *head = t;
}

int main() {
  struct node * head = NULL;
  // we pass &head, the adress of variable head, as parameter:
  add_to_list(&head,1);
  add_to_list(&head,2);

  struct node * n = head;
  while(n != NULL) {
    printf("\nvalue: %d",n->value);
    n = n->next;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all **the function is invalid**. When the list is empty and the first element is added `head` can be equal to `NULL`. So using expression `head->next` that in the function code corresponds to `ptr->next` results in memory access violation.

Also in my opinion it is not a good idea to name `NULL` as `tail`. I would explicitly use `NULL`. Otherwise the code can confuse readers.

Neverteless the function can look the following way

```
struct node * append( int v ) 
{
    struct node *t = ( struct node * )malloc( sizeof( *t ) );
    t->value = v;
    t->next  = tail;

    if ( head == tail )
    {
        head = t;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *current = head;
        while ( current->next != tail ) current = current->next;
        current->next = t;
    }

    return t;
}
```

As for your question then I also do not understand why the function returns `ptr` instead of `t`. It should return `t`. In this case the function would be more correct and efficient  because it would return head when the first element is appended to the empty list and when a next non-first value is appended to the list and the head would be some node (not necessary the head itself) the while loop had no iteration because the first expression `ptr->next` would be equal already to NULL.

The function  should return the last appended node as in the implementation I have shown.

I am sure that **it is simply an error in the design of the function**.:)

This drawback will be more visible if do not use the global variable `head` within the function but declare it as a function parameter. For example

```
struct node * append( struct node *head, int v ) 
{
    struct node *t = ( struct node * )malloc( sizeof( *t ) );
    t->value = v;
    t->next  = tail;

    if ( head == tail )
    {
        head = t;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *current = head;
        while ( current->next != tail ) current = current->next;
        current->next = t;
    }

    return t;
}
```

In this case the function call in main could look for example the following way

```
struct node *head = NULL;

struct node *current;
int i;

head = append( head, 0 );

for ( i = 1, current = head; i < 10; i++ ) current = append( current, i );
```

In this case the call of `append` would be very efficient because within the function the while loop would not make even one iteration.